# How to prevent short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: python, logical-operators, short-circuiting, short-circuit-evaluation

This is a problem that occurred to me while working on a Django project. It's about form validation.

In Django, when you have a submitted form, you can call `is_valid()` on the corresponding form object to trigger the validation and return a Boolean value. So, usually you have code like that inside your view functions:

```py
if form.is_valid():
    # code to save the form data
```

`is_valid()` not only validates the form data but also adds error messages to the form object that can afterwards be displayed to the user.

On one page I use two forms together and also want the data to be saved only if both forms contain valid data. That means I have to call `is_valid()` on both forms before executing the code to save the data. The most obvious way:

```py
if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
    # ...
```

won't work because of the short circuit evaluation of logical operators. If `form1` is not valid, `form2` will not be evaluated and its error messages would be missing.

That's only an example. As far as I know, there is no greedy alternative to `and`/`or` as in other languages (i.e. Smalltalk). I can imagine that problem occurring under different circumstances (and not only in Python). The solutions I could think of are all kind of clumsy (nested `if`s, assigning the return values to local variables and using them in the `if` statement). I would like to know the pythonic way to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

How about something like:

```
if all([form1.is_valid(), form2.is_valid()]):
   ...
```

In a general case, a list-comprehension could be used so the results are calculated up front (as opposed to a generator expression which is commonly used in this context).  e.g.:

```
if all([ form.is_valid() for form in (form1,form2) ])
```

This will scale up nicely to an arbitrary number of conditions as well ... The only catch is that they all need to be connected by "`and`" as opposed to `if foo and bar or baz: ...`.

(for a non-short circuiting `or`, you could use `any` instead of `all`).

Comment: It took me a few seconds to come up with this.  It's a corner case I hadn't considered before (I often work in Fortran which doesn't guarantee short-circuiting, but permits it) and I'm always trying to figure out how to make sure my expressions are short-circuited.  Figuring this out was a bit backwards for me :).

Comment: Yes the `all` is the way to go here, but where did you use list-comprehensions? I only see a simple list on your example.

Comment: @rantanplan -- you're right.  (oops).  I was thinking in the general case a list comprehension could be used.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Also note that the above form can be combined with the solution provided by @BigYellowCactus since `any` and `all` return boolean values.

Answer (score 27):

You can simply use the binary `&` operator, which will do a non-short-circuit logical *AND* on bools.

```
if form1.is_valid() & form2.is_valid():
   ...
```

Comment: More specifically, it will do a bitwise `and` on integers.  Since bools happen to be derived from integers with `True == 1` and `False == 0`, this works.  It won't (necessarily) work for other types or for functions which return things which aren't boolean.  Still, it's a good tool to have around (+1)

Comment: Definitely simpler than the solution by mgilson. Thanks for that! The other one might be more helpful for other people reading the code. Here, I guess you could think I just confused `and` and `&`.

Comment: @mgilson The `all` function was also the first solution that came into my mind (I would use it for exactly the reason j0ker mentioned), but I discoverd the question to late for that answer (+1, btw) :-)

Comment: One advantage over my solution is that you aren't limited to just `and` **if all your results are boolean** (`True`,`False`,`1` or `0`).  You can write an expression like `if foo() & baz() | bar()` which should behave as expected.

Comment: I completely agree with the sentiment that this is generally wrong and works only in special cases, which is very different from the expected behaviour of logic operators in Python.

Comment: Contrary to what some of the other comments here say, this answer is completely correct. In fact, this is specifically designed and intended behavior of bools. `bool` even has its own `bool.__and__` that returns `True` instead of `1` for `True & True`, and similarly for the other bitwise operators, so it's not just inheriting the int implementation (though it is compatible with the int behavior).

Comment: There *is* a potential pitfall with this, which `all` doesn't have - it only works if the return values are actually booleans, it won't test the "truthiness" of non-boolean values. For example, `all([1, 2])` is `True` because `1` and `2` are both truthy, but `1 & 2` is falsy. In some other cases `&` will raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Infix operators](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122/) (ActiveState Python recipe) for defining your own Boolean operators:

```
aand = Infix(lambda x,y: bool(x) and bool(y))
1 |aand| 2  # Will return `True` instead of `1`
```