# Does Python's `all` function use short circuit evaluation?

Tags: python, evaluation, short-circuiting

I wish to use the Python `all()` function to help me compute something, but this something could take substantially longer if the `all()` does not evaluate as soon as it hits a `False`. I'm thinking it probably is short-circuit evaluated, but I just wanted to make sure. Also, is there a way to tell in Python how the function gets evaluated?

---

<sub>**Editor's note**: Because `any` and `all` are **functions**, their arguments must be evaluated before they are called. That often creates the impression of no short-circuiting - but they do still short-circuit.</sub>

<sub>To make sure that the short-circuiting can be effective, pass a *generator expression*, or other lazily evaluated expression, rather than a sequence. See [Lazy function evaluation in any() / all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090762) for details. Similarly, to force evaluation up-front, build a list or tuple explicitly; see [How to prevent short-circuit evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281469) .</sub>

Comment: I reversed the direction of duplicate closure because this version of the question is much more accessible. The previous duplicate question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730046, dives straight into Python test code and ended up as the basis for a bug report against Python's test suite.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it short-circuits:

```
>>> def test():
...     yield True
...     print('one')
...     yield False
...     print('two')
...     yield True
...     print('three')
...
>>> all(test())
one
False
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

> Return `True` if all elements of the *iterable* are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```

So when it `return`s False, then the function immediately breaks.

Comment: What does "yield" do?

Comment: @SylvesterVLowell See [The Python yield keyword explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/395760)

Comment: @SylvesterVLowell Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained). Simply, it's like a return statement, but you can return multiple values. But instead of returning a list, it returns a generator.

Comment: In short, yield is how generators work. If you knew that `all` might short circuit, I guess you knew what generators *do*, just not how they work.

Comment: The part that guarantees short circuiting is here: http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/124237eb5de9

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `all` does use short-circuit evaluation. For example:

```
all(1.0/x < 0.5  for x in [4, 8, 1, 0])
=> False
```

The above stops when `x` reaches `1` in the list, when the condition becomes false. If `all` weren't short-circuiting, we'd get a division by zero when `x` reached `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't do as I did initially which was to try to use short-circuiting to test for the existence of a method before calling it:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...    pass
... 
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> all([hasattr(a, 'b'), a.b()])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'b'
```

but

```
>>> hasattr(a, 'b') and a.b()  # doesn't evaluate a.b() as hasattr(a, 'b') is false
False
```

In the first code snippet, Python evaluates the list before passing it to `all()` so it still throws the exception. This is basically the same as using `list()` to force `all()` not to use short-circuit evaluation as in morningstar's answer

Comment: Python would have to have REALLY lazy evaluation to do what you initially expected.

Comment: I tried to write an answer from scratch that explains the behaviour more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

In answer to your question of whether you can tell `all` to be either short-circuit evaluated or not, it is short-circuit by default, but if you wanted it not to be, you could do this:

```
result = all(list(iterable))
```

Though that has the possibly undesirable property that the whole list will be loaded into memory. I can't think how you would avoid that other than using a different function than all. For example

```
result = reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, iterable)
result = min(iterable) # surprisingly similar to all; YMMV if iterable contains non-booleans
```

Comment: Don't use `min()` as a replacement for `all()` (or `max()` as a replacement for `any()`). `all()` will return `False` as soon as it encounters a falsey object; `min()` will always search the _entire_ iterable to see if there's a “lesser” one. `any()` and `max()` work similarly. Also, the four of them work on any iterable—don't waste time and space making a `list`.

Comment: That eagerly evaluates the iterable, but the actual boolean checking logic still short-circuits. Not that it will usually matter.

Comment: *"if you wanted it not to be"* - Why would you want that? I can't think of any situation off the top of my head.

Comment: @wjandrea, I can't think of a specific example, but if someone wanted to call a function with desired side effects, that returned a boolean, on every item in some iterable, and also compute `all()` on those booleans, I could imagine someone not familiar with short-circuiting using a generator expression inside the call to all and not understanding why the function wasn't called on every item in the iterable.