# Python usage of built in all function on list in return statement

Tags: python, built-in

I have a method, which needs to return the result of multiple checks for equality. It is an implementation of the `__eq__` method of a class, which represents vocables in my application. Here is the code for the return statement:

```
return all((
    self.first_language_translations == other.first_language_translations,
    self.first_language_phonetic_scripts == other.first_language_phonetic_scripts,
    self.second_language_translations == other.second_language_translations,
    self.second_language_phonetic_scripts == other.second_language_phonetic_scripts
))
```

I've tested the runtime of this way of doing it and the other way, using `and` operators. The `and` operators are slightly faster, maybe 0.05s. It seems logical, because of having to create a list of those boolean values first and then running a function, which might do more than what the corresponding `and` operators would have done. However, this is probably going to be executed a lot during my applications runtime.

Now I am wondering, if the usage of `all` in such a case is a good or a bad practice and if it is worth the slowdown, if it is a good practice. My application is all about vocables and might often need to check, whether a vocable or an identical one is already in a list of vocables. It doesn't need to be super fast and I am thinking this might be micro-optimization, so I'd like to use the best practice for such a situation.

Is this a good usage of the built in `all` function?

Comment: I don't think this is any clearer than just using `and`. For such a quick operation, you should choose the implementation that is clearest.

Comment: As well as being clearer to a reader/maintainer, using and is almost certainly quicker because as soon as one of the tests is False it will short-circuit the evaluation (i.e. not evaluate the subsequent expressions) because as soon as one is False the overall result must then be False.

Comment: If the class is basically just a data container, you may want to implement it as a `NamedTuple` instead, which gets you field-based equality comparison for free (among other things).

Comment: @tzaman good suggestion, however, I need them to be mutable and the `__eq__` method is not supposed to check all fields for equality, but only some, while others are meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not a good use of `all()`, since you have a small, fixed number of comparisons to make, and `all()` isn't even letting you represent it any more succinctly than you would when using `and`. Using `and` is more readable, and you should always put readability first *unless you've profiled* and performance is *actually* an issue. That said, using `and` is indeed a tiny bit faster in the worst case, and even faster on average because it'll short circuit on the first `False` rather than executing all the comparisons every time.

Comment: `all` short-circuits also.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246388/does-python-alllist-use-short-circuit-evaluation

Comment: @saulspatz, `all()` itself does short-circuit, but in this case all four comparisons in the OP's code will be executed to create the tuple that is only then being passed to `all()`. Whereas using `and` will only execute the comparisons until the first `False` is reached.

Comment: Aha.  You're correct. I misunderstood your statement.  BTW, I often find `all` to be more readable than a `for` loop, but not in this case, of course.

Comment: @saulspatz, oh sure; I often pass generator expressions to  `all()`.