# Do all() and any() always short-circuit in order?

Tags: python

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246413/2687324, `all()` and `any()` short-circuits. Is the order of evaluation guaranteed?

Using the example from the linked answer:

```
>>> def test():
...     yield True
...     print('one')
...     yield False
...     print('two')
...     yield True
...     print('three')
...
>>> all(test())
one
False
```

Will the result always be `one` and `False`?

Comment: It will iterate the iterable in the order of the iterable. If the iterable order of your iterable is stable, so is `all`/`any`.

Comment: @deceze Quick question: What would an unstable iterable look like?

Comment: An iterable using the `random` function?

Comment: As a side note, it is really hard to imagine a reasonable implementation that would short-circuit in an order different to the iteration order. I would even argue that this would break the very definition of *short-circuit evaluation*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) :

> **all(iterable)**
>
> Return `True` if all elements of the *iterable* are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```

So as said in the comments the answer is yes, if the order of your iterable is stable.