# Any/All python short-circuit: Why doesn't the following work?

Tags: python, short-circuiting

Based on what I've seen on other stackoverflow pages:

- [Does Python's `all` function use short circuit evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246388/does-alllist-use-short-circuit-evaluation/17246413#17246413)
- [Do all() and any() always short-circuit in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508350/do-all-and-any-always-short-circuit-in-order)
- [Is the shortcircuit behaviour of Python's any/all explicit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730046/is-the-shortcircuit-behaviour-of-pythons-any-all-explicit)

the following code should short circuit:

```
any([True, 2+2, False, 2/0])
all([True, 2+2, False, 2/0])
```

but for every one of them I get a `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`.

Am I missing something? Why does it error?

Comment: `False and 2/0` and `True and 2/0` short circuit evaluation happens

Comment: After reviewing the links, I decided that a) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246388 should be the canonical version of the question; b) what you are asking is not a separate question, but an important clarification that was not properly covered there. So I added duplicate links and wrote my own answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code errors because the expressions have to be evaluated before being passed into the function.

In this context, short-circuiting actually means that as soon as they find a different value, they return and don't bother checking the remaining values. It's not the same kind of short-circuiting that `and` and `or` do, which can actually avoid evaluating expressions.

To illustrate, let's use an iterator, which will get consumed:

```
>>> a = iter([1, 0, 2, 3])
>>> all(a)  # Search until a falsy value
False
>>> list(a)  # Show what's left in the iterator
[2, 3]
```

You can see that it consumed `1` and `0`, returning on `0` because it's falsy.

---

Now, if you did want to do lazy evaluation with `any` and `all`, you could call lambdas in a generator expression:

```
>>> any(e() for e in [lambda: 1, lambda: 0, lambda: 2/0])
True
>>> all(e() for e in [lambda: 1, lambda: 0, lambda: 2/0])
False
```

(Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64090762/4518341) for inspiring this bit.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, short circuting happens in python

```
In [23]: False and 3/0
Out[23]: False

In [24]: True and 3/0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-a08823d6496a> in <module>
----> 1 True and 3/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Using the dis module,

```
In [32]: dis.dis("all([True, 2+2, False, 2/0])")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (all)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
              8 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             10 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             12 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
             14 BUILD_LIST               4
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 RETURN_VALUE

In [33]: dis.dis("any(True, 2+2, False, 2/0)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (any)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
              8 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             10 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             12 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            4
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

When you look at the function calls,  `BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE` is evaluated before `any` or `all` because expressions get evaluated first before any function call