# How can I make the short-circuiting of Python's any() and all() functions effective (avoid evaluation before the function call)?

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, any, short-circuiting

Python's `any` and `all` built-in functions [are supposed to short-circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246388/), like the logical operators `or` and `and` do.

However, suppose we have a function definition like so:

```py
def func(s):
    print(s)
    return True
```

and use it to build a list of values passed to `any` or `all`:

```
>>> any([func('s'), func('t')])
's'
't'
True
```

Since the list must be constructed before `any` is called, the function is also evaluated ahead of time, [effectively preventing the short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281469).

If the function calls are expensive, evaluating all the functions up front is a big loss and is a waste of this ability of `any`.

Knowing that [`any` accepts any kind of iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), how can we defer the evaluation of `func`, so that the short-circuiting of `any` prevents the call of `func(t)`?

Comment: There are all manner of iterator producing things in Python. For example `map()`: `any(map(func, ('s', 't')))`. Most people seem to have the opposite problem in Python3 — they want list outputs and python gives them generators and maps!

Comment: This has nothing to do with `any`. The evaluations happen while constructing the list.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We can use a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression), passing the functions and their arguments separately and evaluating only in the generator like so:

```py
>>> any(func(arg) for arg in ('s', 't'))
's'
True
```

For different functions with different signatures, this could look like the following:

```py
any(
    f(*args)
    for f, args in [(func1, ('s',)), (func2, (1, 't'))]
)
```

That way, `any` will stop iterating over the generator as soon as one function call evaluates to `True`, and that means that the function evaluation is fully lazy.

Another neat way to postpone the function evaluation  is to use [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), like so:

```py
>>> any(
...     f() 
...     for f in [lambda: func('s'), lambda: func('t')]
... )
's'
True
```

Answer (score -4):

It is sad that `any()` and `all()` don't have the logical functionality and are limited by this somewhat artificial constraint. Instead, a once-thru loop construction can be handy, particularly if there are intermediate results that need to be generated and used. This is related also to a function with early returns.

```
def example():

    for _ in range(1):
        val = func1()
        if not val:
            break
        val1 = intermediate_func1(val)
        if not func3(val1):
            break
        val2 = intermediate_func2(val1)
        if not func4(val2):
            break
        result = the_really_expensive_function(val, val2)
        if result:
            return True, result
    return False, None
```

similar construct using a function and early returns.

```
def example():
    val = func1()
    if not val:
        return False, None
    val1 = intermediate_func1(val)
    if not func3(val1):
        return False, None
    val2 = intermediate_func2(val1)
    if not func4(val2):
        return False, None
    result = the_really_expensive_function(val, val2)
    if result:
        return True, result
    return False, None
```

What I wanted to use (but can't; and this is only feasible with `:=` operator):

```
if all(
        val := func1(),
        func3(val1 := intermediate_func1(val)),
        func4(val2 := intermediate_func2(val1)),
        result := the_really_expensive_function(val, val2),
        ):
    return True, result
return False, None
```

Maybe in the future this will be feasible.

Comment: The first example here is missing a function definition. Could you [edit] to fix it?

Comment: *"somewhat artificial constraint"* - Eh? It's entirely a practical constraint. You can't build a list (or other collection) without knowing the contents, so the calls in OP's code *have to be* evaluated ahead of time.

Comment: It may be practical, but it isn't efficient. It is best not to use all() because it won't stop early, and therefore, I avoid it. I could be written to evaluate each of the all() items one at a time and not evaluate them all. It could have been written that way.

Comment: What you're trying to do with `if all(val := func1(), func3(val1 := intermediate_func1(val)), func4(val2 := intermediate_func2(val1)), result := the_really_expensive_function(val, val2)):` becomes `if (val := func1()) and (func3(val1 := intermediate_func1(val))) and (func4(val2 := intermediate_func2(val1))) and (result := the_really_expensive_function(val, val2)):`