# How to check for float('nan') in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

In some data I am processing I am encountering data of the type `float`, which are filled with 'nan', i.e. `float('nan')`.

However checking for it does not work as expected:

```py
float('nan') == float('nan')
>> False
```

You can check it with `math.isnan`, but as my data also contains strings (For example: 'nan', but also other user input), it is not that convenient:

```py
import math
math.isnan(float('nan'))
>> True
math.isnan('nan')
>> TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

In the ideal world I would like to check if a value is in a list of all possible NaN values, for example:

```py
import numpy as np
if x in ['nan', np.nan, ... ]:
    # Do something
    pass
```

Now the question:
**How can I still use this approach but also check for `float('nan')` values? And why equals `float('nan') == float('nan')` `False`**

Comment: `if x == 'nan' or isnan(x)`…?!

Comment: Better yet, use `isnan` and clean your data so you don't have to worry about 'or is it actually a string?'

Comment: The `if x == 'nan' or isnan(x)` will raise a TypeError if x is not a real number. Cleaning up is one solution but I would prefer to do everything in one go if possible. Also I am still curious why `float('nan) == float('nan')` equals `False`

Comment: "but as my data also contains strings" - it sounds like you should fix that issue first, then use `isnan`.

Comment: "Also I am still curious why float('nan) == float('nan') equals False" - because it was designed so `x != x` would be a convenient way to test for NaN in settings without an `isnan` function (common in the early days of IEEE 754), and because having the comparison produce `True` isn't actually more useful.

Comment: If you're doing a comparison `x == y` and `x` and `y` are both NaNs produced by invalid floating-point operations, `True` isn't actually a more useful outcome than `False`. On the other hand, if you're looking for a nan check, `x != x` does that, so `x == nan` doesn't need to be a nan check too.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I had not realised your last point - `x != x` is cool. Side effects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just wrap whatever you pass to `math.isnan` with another `float` conversion? If it was already a float (i.e. `float('nan')`) you just made a "redundant" call:

```
import math

def is_nan(value):
    return math.isnan(float(value))
```

And this seems to give your expected results:

```
>>> is_nan(float('nan'))
True
>>> is_nan('nan')
True
>>> is_nan(np.nan)
True
>>> is_nan(5)
False
>>> is_nan('5')
False
```

---

This will still raise a `ValueError` for non-numeric (except `'nan'`) strings. If that's a problem, you can wrap with `try/except`. As long as the `float` conversion worked, there is no reason for `isnan` to fail. So we are basically catching non-numeric strings that my fail the `float` conversion:

```py
def is_nan(value):
    try:
        return math.isnan(float(value))
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Any non-numeric string is surely not a NaN value so `return False`.

Comment: And it still works with "other strings" that aren't `'nan'`? Won't that throw a different `TypeError`?

Comment: @jtlz2 To be fair, after correcting my comment under your answer, both codes you provided will have the exact same problem...

Comment: Touché - good spot :\

Answer (score 4):

It's very pedestrian, and a bit ugly, but why not just do the following?

```py
import math
import numpy as np

if math.isnan(x) or x in ['nan', np.nan, ... ]:
    # Do something
    pass
```

I want to recommend a Yoda expression but haven't quite worked it out yet.

If you want to sweep everything under the carpet put it in a lambda or function.

Following on from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64090763/1021819, you can try to get the iterator to evaluate any in a lazy fashion. The problem then is that if none of the first conditions evaluates to `True` then the `math.isnan()` call is executed and can still throw the `TypeError`. If you evaluate lazily you can guard the `math.isnan()` call with a type check against `str`:

```py
fn_list_to_check=[
    lambda x: x in ['nan', np.nan, ... ],
    lambda x: not isinstance(x, str),
    lambda x: math.isnan(x)
    ]

if any(f(x) for f in fn_list_to_check):
    # Do something
    pass
```

Note the absence of square list brackets in the any i.e. `any()` not `any([])` (who knew?).

I think it's quite brilliant but equally as ugly - choose your poison.

For the second part of the question (why `float('nan') != float('nan')`), see

[What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Comment: If `x` is a string the `math.isnan(x)` call will raise a `TypeError`. We could ofcourse check if it is a string first, but I was hoping to find a more direct method

Comment: You can put it in a helper function in the worst case.

Comment: Now I'm wondering about a chain of filters.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) (or opposite `notnull`) handles all the exceptions `math.isnan` and `np.isnan` do not, such as strings and `None`.

```
import pandas as pd
for x in [float('nan'), 'nan', np.NaN, None, 'None', '']:
    pd.isnull(x)

True
False
True
True
False
False
```

Note pandas is a large import, but if you're already using it (which you may well be if you're doing a lot of data processing), it's handy.

Answer (score -3):

You can check for NaN value like this,

```
 def isNaN(num):
    if num == 'nan':
        return True
    return num!= num
```

Comment: `'nan' != 'nan'` Gives `False`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo corrected!