# Why do `any` and `all` not appear to use short-circuit evaluation here?

Tags: python

Does `all()` return False right after finding a False in a sequence?
Try to run this code:

```
def return_true():
    print('I have just been printed')
    return True

print(all((False, return_true())))
```

As you can see, `I have just been printed` is printed even though there is False before it.

Another example:

```
def return_false():
    print('I have just been printed')
    return False

print(any((True, return_false())))
```

In this case, `I have just been printed` is printed in this code even though there is True before.

Comment: I decided that with an appropriate title, this is not really a duplicate. However, see also: [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/) and [Lazy Function Evaluation in any() / all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090762/).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246388

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `all()` and `any()` both short circuit the way you describe. `all()` will return early if any item is false-y, and `any()` will if any item is truthy.

The reason you're seeing the printouts is because `return_true()` and `return_false()` are being called before `all` and `any` are even invoked. They must be. A function's arguments have to be evaluated before the function is called, after all.

This:

> ```
> print(all((False, return_true())))
> ```

is equivalent to:

```
x = return_true()
print(all((False, x)))
```

i.e. `return_true()` is evaluated unconditionally.

To get the desired short-circuiting behavior, the *sequence itself* needs to be evaluated lazily. One simple way to do this is to make an iterable, not of the values we want to test, but of *things we can call* to get those values; and then use a generator expression to create a sequence that lazily calls them. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090762/python-lazy-function-evaluation-in-any-all).

Here, that might look like:

```
print(all(
    x()
    for x in (lambda: False, return_true)
))

print(any(
    x()
    for x in (lambda: True, return_false)
))
```

Comment: *"A function's arguments have to be evaluated before the function is called"* - You'd [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) so. Just kidding, although I do only know that word [thanks to Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/079f0dd7191fbadd4c3a5899b6af12492e84d2b4/Lib/linecache.py#L16).

Answer (score 2):

What you may be looking for is just a plain old `if` with conditions connected by `and`:

```
def return_true():
    print('I have just been printed')
    return True

if False and return_true():
    print('inside if')
```

This prints **nothing**! A true short-circuit operator with no extra evaluations.

---

**SEE ALSO:**

`all` source code: search for `builtin_all` here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c

Comment: Yes, in trivial cases it certainly makes more sense to do this. `Simple is better than complex`. However, this doesn't really extend to the case where the sequence of conditions is customizable at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You already compute all values before `all` is even called. Here's another way to avoid that, a generator:

```
def return_true():
    print('I have just been printed')
    return True

def values():
    yield False
    yield return_true()

print(all(values()))
```