# Using "if all(cond1, cond2, ...)" instead of "if cond1 and cond2 and ..."

Tags: python

I think writing

```
if condition_1 \
        and condition_2 \
        ...
       and condition_43:
    do_stuff()
```

seems ugly.

I thought about doing:

```
if all((
    condition_1,
    condition_2,
    ...
    condition_43,
)):
    do_stuff()
```

This works as long `condition_j` can be executed independent of `condition_i` (j > i). This is not always the case, e.g. one want to do `some_file.exists()` before `os.path.getsize(some_file) > 0`.

Is there a way writing the tuple `(condition_1, condition_2, ..., condition_43)` in a way that it is interpreted as generator expression and evaluated one one by one inside the `all` function and not before the `all` function is called?

(I know I could move the code in a separate function and could work with yields or similar but I specifically want to do this.)

Comment: Wouldn't having two or more `all` clauses work? `all(independent) and all(dependent) and...`

Comment: Come to think of it, isn't short circuiting guaranteed for `any`/`all`? I don't think your problem would be an issue.

Comment: Is it just the backslashes that are untidy? You could `if (c1 and c2 and c3):` and now you can add newlines without backslashes because you are in a parenthesied group. That's much better than generator hacks.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal - the challenge is that its the function result that is tested in the `all`. You couldn't write a tuple of conditions because all of the functions would be called before you get to the call to `all`. So, you could have a generator fed a tuple of function object and its *args and **kwargs ... but yuck.

Comment: I guess the lambda hack in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090762/lazy-function-evaluation-in-any-all does the trick...

Comment: @Victor It's not a hack, that's exactly what functions are for: defining code then running it later, as needed :)