# How to / is that possible to turn off short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: python

I am coding a kind of command line user interface where an arbitrary boolean expression can be given as input. This expression must be repeatedly evaluated on a dictionary that is changing after some update.

Here is the simplified code :

```
import traceback


def update_my_dict():
    return {'a': 1}


my_dict = {'a': 0}

bool_exp = input()

# -- verify code can be executed in the current context
try:
    result = eval(bool_exp, my_dict)
except Exception:
    print(f'Expression cannot be evaluated, evaluation raise the following error:')
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    quit()

# -- verify code return a boolean
if not isinstance(result, bool):
    print(f'Expression return {type(result)}, expect bool')
    quit()

# -- go
while not eval(bool_exp, my_dict):
    my_dict = update_my_dict()
```

Before running the last while loop I want to verify that the expression can be executed in the current context and ensuring that its return a boolean.

My problem is if the expression is, for example `bool_exp = a == 1 and b == 2` the first test evaluation of the expression while return false but do not raise exception because off lazy evaluation. But when `my_dict` is updated then an error will be raised.

So is that possible to, some how, disable the lazy/short-circuit evaluation for the first test evaluation ? I searched some solution using [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), but it seems complicated since `bool_exp` can be arbitrary long and complex, like containing entangled boolean expressions and so on.

*PS: I know `eval()` is unsafe in a general context but my code will not be usable externaly*

*PS2: I know its possible to catch the exception in the while loop but it looks a bit sub-optimized knowing `my_dict` keys will never change when updated, only their values. Also this question is more like if its possible to control the evaluation behavior*

## EDIT

"but you could use `&` and `|` instead of `and` and `or` !"
No. I cannot tell what will be entered as input. So the user can input whatever s.he want.

A Correct input expression:

1. Should return a boolean.
2. Should only involve dictionary keys in the tests.

"Correct" meaning it will be repeatedly evaluated in the ending while loop without raised any exception.
We assume that the keys in the dictionary will stay constant. i.e only the values of the dict will change during the update phase. In other words, the first `try/except` aim to verify that the expression is only doing some test on variables that are in `my_dict`.

I cannot explain further the global use of this or I'll need a very long post with lost of what seems irrelevant information to resolve the issue.

Comment: The unwanted behaviour is better described as 'short-circuit boolean evaluation'. Lazy evaluation is a different thing. Maybe editing your question along these lines will encourage answers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Avoid short circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281469/python-avoid-short-circuit-evaluation)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve and how it depends on "lazy evaluation"? From what I am gathering, your issue is that ``a == 1 and b == 2`` allows ``b`` to be undefined when ``a`` equals ``1`` – and you consider this "invalid". But what exactly is your *criteria* for "invalid"? Would ``a == "12"`` be invalid? Would ``a == 12 and []`` be invalid? What about ``a == a and b``? How is ``my_dict`` updated anyway?

Comment: What is "the first test evaluation of the expression"? Is that your first iteration of the while loop or your first `eval` in your first `try/catch` block? (Just trying to fully digest the question).  Also, what is happening in your dictionary that it uses the evaluation of this string expression and errors out?

Comment: May I ask what is it that you really want to achieve with this code?

Comment: @L.Grozinger have you read my question and the other one ? My input are arbitrary so I cannot modify the code that is evaluated. Not like this other question.

Comment: @Welgriv but the problem is the boolean operators right? which you could easily `replace` with non-short-circtuiing counterparts `&` and `|` as is suggested in the answer to the linked question?

Comment: @L.Grozinger I cannot tell if the input will be composed with `and` `or` or `&` an `|` because its an.... input ! you got it ! :)

Comment: @L.Grozinger The binary operators ``&`` and ``|`` have different precedence than the logical operators ``and`` and ``or``. Most importantly, they are on opposite sides of the comparison operators ``==``, ``<``, ….

Comment: @MisterMiyagi very good point! Maybe there is a solution for that also...

Comment: I think the proper solution is not to repurpose the Python language/evaluation for something that is desired to have different semantics. :/

Comment: Why not have all that "verification" code as part of the loop?

Comment: If you want to stick to using Python to evaluate this, you can inspect the AST of the source code to check for free variables and reject any unwanted operations. Trying to change evaluation semantics will be neither feasible nor sufficient for your goal.

Comment: @Tomerikoo please read the post until the end. Its because it certainly be slower. And its also dumb because expression will be evaluate twice.

Comment: No it will not. You are already evaluating it with each update: `while not eval(bool_exp, my_dict):`. The only added operation is `if not isinstance(result, bool):` which I ***highly*** doubt will affect the performance in any way

Comment: @Tomerikoo I really don't get how adding some code in the loop will not slow it down even a little ?? Beside its *possible* to verify the correctness of the expression before so it does not seems to be a satisfying workaround.

Comment: I might not have read all the comments here, but 1) If you are planning on using the builtin `eval(..)`, you no option around lazy evaluation, 2) What I'd do is do an `ast.literal_eval(..)`, and walk the tree and evaluate it myself.

Comment: @Tomerikoo cannot open your link without an account

Comment: @UltraInstinct yes `eval()` does optimize around lazy evaluation. Just test it and you'll see.

Comment: I've hammered open the question since the duplicate does not apply. The expression is provided as arbitrary input; manually inputting a "better" input is not possible in this situation.

Comment: @Welgriv: Yes, I know :). What I meant to say was you will have to write your own evaluator the hard way -- if the input is going to be arbitrary. I don't see any way around that to achieve what you're hoping for. Any and all hacks being suggested here will have likely gotchas.

Comment: @Welgriv To do this properly it will need "some solution using ast" and that frankly takes some work to write down correctly. If someone makes the effort, it will take some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the "verification" code ***inside*** the loop. This makes sense as your input is changing so you should verify it on each change. You already `eval`uate the expression every time the dict values change, so the only added logic compared to your current code is that the `isinstance` check is now done as well with every change of the dict:

```py
import traceback

def update_my_dict():
    return {'a': 1}

my_dict = {'a': 0}

bool_exp = input()

# -- go
while True:
    # -- verify code can be executed in the current context
    try:
        result = eval(bool_exp, my_dict)
    except Exception:
        print(f'Expression cannot be evaluated, evaluation raise the following error:')
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        quit()

    # -- verify code return a boolean
    if not isinstance(result, bool):
        print(f'Expression return {type(result)}, expect bool')
        quit()

    if result:
        break

    my_dict = update_my_dict()
```

On the same example input `a == 1 and b == 2` this will output:

```
Expression cannot be evaluated, evaluation raise the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    result = eval(bool_exp, my_dict)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```